# Setting indepedent states to Java enum values

Tags: java, enums

I'm fairly new to Java Enums and I'm currently trying to implement an Enum list where each of the values have some True/False value associated with each. My enum list looks like this essentially:

```
public enum SomeEnum{
    A("A"),
    B("B"),
    C("C"),
    D("D");
    private String name;
    private SomeEnum(String name){
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

However, I want each enum value to have a "TRUE" or "FALSE" associated with it. Is this plausible with Java enums? Or would I need to approach it without using enums. Ultimately I'd like to have some setter/getter method to set and get each status independently.

Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry for being confusing, I wasn't exactly clear on what I wanted do do. I'm creating a message set for DDS and would like to create a message set for a panel of status messages that show either TRUE or FALSE respectively and can be changed. I figured I could somehow do this using enums instead of creating a separate instance of each variable.

Comment: In your case you don't need to provide a name if it's the same as one of the enum's values. you could reach it via SomeEnum.A.name()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: depends on your use case. It is perfectly plausible to have something like this:

```
public enum SomeEnum{
    A(true),
    B(false),
    C(true),
    D(false);

    private boolean myBool;

    private SomeEnum(boolean myBool){
        this.myBool = myBool;
    }

    public boolean geMyBool() {
        return myBool;
    }
}
```

Don't use the `name` as the name of your field though because the `String` representation of the name of an enum value (`A`, `B` etc) is used as a `name` of all `enum` values in Java. So for example `SomeEnum.A.getName()` equals "A". This functionality is built in for all enums.

Please also note that if you set the value of `myBool` it will confuse the users of your enum because the runtime state will be inconsistent with the value present in the source code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

However, Is it possible to use enums and overide the boolean of each enum? From my understanding the true/false bools are static/final when set in the enum list. Is it possible to have an external variable to assign to each enum separately?

Comment: @KyleKW could you add some pseudocode to show what do you want to do with this enums?

Comment: I fixed my answer. It would be cool if you could share your use case.

Comment: Typically if you want to change stuff you should not use `enum`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum SomeEnum{
    A("A", true),
    B("B", false),
    C("C", false),
    D("D", true);

    private String name;
    private boolean isImportant;

    private SomeEnum(String name, boolean isImportant){
        this.name = name;
        this.isImportant = isImportant;
    }
```

}

Comment: Great Alex. How do you get the value of that isImportant flag? You need to add a getter method for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are near to the solution, just add a new param to the constructor

```
public enum SomeEnum{ 
    A("A", true),
    B("B", false),
    C("C", true),
    D("D", false);

    private String name;
    private boolean flag;

    private SomeEnum(String name, boolean flag){
    this.name = name;
    this.flag = flag;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and it is simple to do.

```
    public enum SomeEnum{
    A(true),
    B(false),
    C(true),
    D(false);
    private boolean flag;
    private SomeEnum(boolean flag){
      this.flag = flag;
    }

    public boolean getFlag() {
      return flag;
    }
}
```

Also you don't need to do name variable since enum already has a method called `name()` that returns you a String representing the name of your instance. If you want the String to be dfferent just override method `toString()` and use it to get a String that is not the same as your enum instance name